# Randomly toggle CSS tag using JS JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, cursor

I'm making a random image that changes when the mouse enter in a div with `testarea` class.

Mouse enter Div, toggle the 'off-cursor' tag of the image randomly.

I have referred to several sites.

but, I am JS and JQUERY beginners. I don't know how to complete it.

I'd be very grateful if you could help me.

```js
const Cursor = document.querySelectorAll('.cursor');

function getRdCursor() {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * Cursor.length);
  return Cursor[index];
};
  
  $(function () {
  $(".testarea").mousemove(function (e) {
    $(".cursor").show().css({
      "left": e.clientX,
      "top": e.clientY
    });
  }).mouseout(function () {
    $(".cursor").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.testarea {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  cursor: none;

}
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  height: auto;
  left: -100px;
  cursor: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.off-cursor {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/tJ1jipvvMs4r7xuZnI/giphy.gif" alt="Cursor" class="cursor" />
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/XFpIo4jKuUrjQHYHeq/giphy.gif" alt="Cursor" class="cursor off-cursor" />
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/uxunn6z4qKrGsND3II/giphy.gif" alt="Cursor" class="cursor off-cursor" />
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/XxRl7rbKSFvXEFoNzv/giphy.gif" alt="Cursor" class="cursor off-cursor" />

<div class="testarea"></div>
<div class="testarea"></div>
<div class="testarea"></div>
<div class="testarea"></div>
```

Comment: You can use `Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".cursor").length)` to get a random index of a cursor to turn on.

Comment: wow, I didn't think about that. thank you.